# Doctrine2 - How set oneToOne entity not by id

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

That is part of mapping info:

```
id:
    type: integer
    id: true
    generator:
        strategy: AUTO
ms_id:
    type: string
    unique: true
oneToOne:
    parent:
        targetEntity: Category
        nullable: true
```

How do I establish a connection with ms_id instead of the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the join column parameters with  **referencedColumnName**,
see the [association mapping document](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

```
id:
    type: integer
    id: true
    generator:
        strategy: AUTO
ms_id:
    type: string
    unique: true
oneToOne:
    parent:
        targetEntity: Category
        joinColumn:
          name: category_id
          referencedColumnName: ms_id
        nullable: true
```

Comment: Thanks... I tried to do it, but its require drop and create db at first.